# Matplotlib - Show legend with multiple colours representing the same value

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm making plots where there are multiple bars displaying the same statistic but over different time periods.  I want to create a legend which displays both colours for a particular value in the same line.  See the attached graph (made in excel) as an example.[image: Graph I'd like to make]

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's interested I found a pseudo hack which does what I want.  Using the `ncol=2` command in the legend properties and setting the second set of legend titles to just `''` it displays correctly.  The only hassle is formatting the labels with space padding to make the labels look center justified.

For example, the code below produced the legend in the image shown at the bottom of this post:

```
plt.legend((p3[0], p2[0], p1[0],p7, p6[0], p5[0], p4[0]),
           ('       Maximum','  90th Percentile','        Average' ,'    MOE Guideline', '', '', ''), ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @tcaswell: I just use the normal legend command with ncol as an argument.  `plt.legend((p3[0], p2[0], p1[0],p7, p6[0], p5[0], p4[0]),
               ('       Maximum','  90th Percentile','        Average' ,'    MOE Guideline', '', '', ''), ncol=2)`.  You will just have to play with the blank entries to make it look correct.

Comment: edit your answer to include that, comments are unreadable and unstable.  This seems like something useful and should be preserved.

Comment: @tcaswell: let me know if there's anything that's still unclear.  Cheers.

Comment: looks good.  I suspect that there are ways by using text alignment and column spacing to automate the text location code.